# Using getShortClassName() method in Android

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

I'm trying to modify an application to use the getShortClassName() method instead of displaying the full class name (e.g. "com.google.app.MainActivity" to simply ".MainActivity"). The current setup gives me no errors but doesn't display the text.

I presume the solution is not complicated, although I just don't have the experience to make it work. Help?

```html
 @Override
 public View getChildView (int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  MyActivityInfo activity = (MyActivityInfo)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_activities_child_item, null);

  TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
  text1.setText(activity.getName());

        //TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        //text2.setText(activity.getComponentName().getClassName());

  TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
  text2.setText(activity.getShortClassName());
 
  ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
  icon.setImageDrawable(activity.getIcon());

  return view;
 }
```

```html
public class MyActivityInfo implements Comparable<MyActivityInfo> {
 public MyActivityInfo(ComponentName activity, PackageManager pm) {
  this.component_name = activity;

  ActivityInfo act;
  try {
   act = pm.getActivityInfo(activity, 0);
   this.name = act.loadLabel(pm).toString();
   try {
    this.icon = (BitmapDrawable)act.loadIcon(pm);
   }
   catch(ClassCastException e) {
    this.icon = (BitmapDrawable)pm.getDefaultActivityIcon();
   }
   this.icon_resource = act.getIconResource();
  } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
   this.name = activity.getShortClassName();
   this.icon = (BitmapDrawable)pm.getDefaultActivityIcon();
   this.icon_resource = 0;
  }

  this.icon_resource_name = null;
  if(this.icon_resource != 0) {
   try {
    this.icon_resource_name = pm.getResourcesForActivity(activity).getResourceName(this.icon_resource);
   } catch (Exception e) {}
  }
 }

 public ComponentName getComponentName() {
  return component_name;
 }

 public BitmapDrawable getIcon() {
  return icon;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public String getIconResourceName() {
  return icon_resource_name;
 }

    public String getShortClassName() {
        return class_name;
    }

 protected ComponentName component_name;
 protected BitmapDrawable icon;
 protected int icon_resource;
 protected String icon_resource_name;
 protected String name;
    protected String class_name;


 @Override
 public int compareTo(MyActivityInfo another) {
  int cmp_name = this.name.compareTo(another.name);
  if (cmp_name != 0) return cmp_name;

  int cmp_component = this.component_name.compareTo(another.component_name);
  return cmp_component;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object other) {
  if(!other.getClass().equals(MyPackageInfo.class)) {
   return false;
  }

  MyActivityInfo other_info = (MyActivityInfo)other;
  return this.component_name.equals(other_info.component_name);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use getSimpleName() method of class object:

```
    String a = "Hello";
    System.out.println(a.getClass().getSimpleName());
    System.out.println(a.getClass().getName());
```

Output:

```
String
java.lang.String
```